# why is the reminders app missing from iOS7 simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, reminders

Hi i have an app that uses the reminders app to set a reminder with an alarm but the problem is that on the iOS7 simulator there is no app icon to the reminders app so i cannot open it up to see if the reminder has been set. Has anyone else had this problem or does anyone know how to fix it?

thanks

Comment: Test your app on a real iOS device. Submit a bug report to Apple asking them to add the Reminders app to the simulator.